# "Featured on Meta" is confusing

Tags: feature-request, bounties, wording, featured-tag

Whenever a question on MSE is tagged as [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), ALL sites will show a "Featured on Meta" section on the right (desktop web). Meanwhile, among the question filter tabs one reads "featured". That would really make people think "FoM" means "A question on Meta has an open bounty". Maybe we should replace either of them.

- "featured¹" → "bonus"/"rewarding"
- "featured²" → "announcement"/"highlighted"
- "Featured² on Meta" (full phrase) → "**Stack Exchange Spotlight**" (personally preferred)

Comment: So a request to change this is a featured request?

Comment: @ItamarG3 It's a bug actually. I'm only giving possible fixes but I agree this can also be tagged feat-req.

Comment: the featured has only one meaning. in main site, you have to pay to get your question feature(in the form of rep) and in meta, the mods can feature a question

Comment: @SagarV But not for MSE where both bounties and mod tags exists.

Comment: FWIW, that widget used to be called 'Community Bulletin'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually like it that they use the same term. It describes the 'resulting state' of the question; a question deserving and getting more attention than a regular question. The fact that it uses two different methods (a user spending reputation on a bounty vs. a ♦ moderator applying a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag – this can also happen on child metas) is irrelevant.